# How to contact linux ClearCase clients from Windows servers

Tags: linux, windows, clearcase

I am working on trying to get some linux Clearcase clients to work with our existing Windows infrastructure.  All of the vobs and servers are stored on Windows machines.

Using an existing vob, I was able to create a tag in the linux region to refer to the vob, and then create a view on the linux client.  This client was able to connect to the vob and pull the files in when I updated the config spec.  However, while it can view files, it does not have permission to edit them.

The usernames match

linux:  user1
windows: DOMAIN\user1

The Clearcase admin panel is set to "Use this domain to map UNIX user and group names" with DOMAIN selected.

However, the authentication does not appear to be working.  From the unix client, if I run

```
credmap windowsServer
```

I get Nobody/Nobody for the remote username and group ID.  If I run from the Windows server

```
credmap linuxClient
```

It times out and I get

```
credmap: Error: Unable to contact albd_server on host
```

Investigating further albd_list on unix shows that the albd server is running, and even finds the albd_server on the windows machine.

```
albd_server addr = 166.20.20.81, port= 371

albd_list 166.20.17.118
albd_server addr = 166.20.17.118, port= 371
```

Going in the opposite direction returns

```
albd_list 166.20.20.81
noname: Error: Unable to contact albd_server on host '166.20.20.81'
cannot contact albd
```

Ping works from the windows host to the linux host, and I am even connected to the linux host by SSH from the parent at the moment.

If anyone has any ideas on what to look for next, you'd be my hero :(

Comment: Use CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) in linux?

Comment: Did you consider migrating to a free software version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/), etc... ?

Comment: Yes, we are considering that as well.  However, getting this working for right now would still be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You get limited ClearCase functionality when you access a ClearCase server (running on Windows) from a Linux client. To learn more, read about [CCFS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146338).

I'd suggest you to consider migrating your VOB server to Linux. This way you get all ClearCase functionality, including dynamic views.

Comment: Thanks, and I am aware that dynamic views won't work.  If I had my way we wouldn't have any Windows machines at all lol... but I do not have my way and replacing our IT infrastructure is beyond the scope of my mission.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm having Vob server on windows mean they won't be fully accessible from linux client, even though the official documentation from IBM describes the CCFS setting to follow.
(See "[Configure UNIX or Linux clients to access Windows VOBs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21141329)", which you must have seen)

In particular, I never managed to have a credential mapping fully working from Linux to windows (the other way works well).
And you need to make sure your view storage is accessible from Linux (see "[Creating a view on a NAS device](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_viewadm_mkview_nas.htm)")

That leaves you with inter-environment solutions, like:

- CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client, for CC7.x)
- ClearTeam (for CC 8.x)

See "[Feature Comparison Matrix for CCRC, CTE, CCWeb, Native ClearCase GUI and SCM Adapter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233090)".

Answer (score 1):

This wound up being something stupid.  There was a firewall running on the linux machine blocking the albd_server port.

This also did not resolve the credential mapping issues, but it at least let me eliminate one more potential cause.  Thanks